My son installed a cpu upgrade without a bios update and now has no display. The old cpu is damaged is a new motherboard the only fix?
Is there a way to flash the bios without going back to the previous cpu. He had a ryzen 5 with a gigabyte gx 370 gaming 3, he installed a amd ryzen 7 5700x. The bios is the only issue with the compatibility conflict. Otherwise is a new motherboard an option

I put tto you the problem is that the Ryzen 7 5700X CPU does not have a built in GPU which is why the screen is blank (https://www.amd.com/en/product/11826)  - and no amount of BIOS flashing can fix it (nor can a new motherboard).   Maybe consider buying a discrete GPU ?

We have a msi geforce 1070ti 8gb

If so then no, you have to install the compatible CPU again, flash the new firmware (it may take more than one step because a certain minimum version is required in order to upgrade to the latest one), then finally install the new CPU and it should work.

Go to a computer store and pay them to upgrade for you? If they are a decent size they will probably have a suitable CPU to use?

@ChanganAuto you should post that as an answer.

@music2myear Thank you for noticing, Reworded for an answer and posted as you suggested.

If the board has a BIOS recovery function over USB, that might work.

@DanielB Indeed. However, assuming the OP meant the "GA-AX370-Gaming 3 (rev. 1.x)", the closest match to what was posted, then the manufacturer makes no mention/claim about such feature (the DualBIOS™ is a fallback feature).

@ChanganAuto I don't believe that's what was being referred to - please see my prior comment

@JW0914 The possibility to flash the firmware as you describe is becoming more common nowadays but far from your stated "most motherboards have [it]" (and when they have it's usually front and center in the product's page, that being an USP and all...). Please note this motherboard precedes the first  generation of motherboards with that feature by a couple of years.

While researching, I also found this FAQ entry. It basically suggests that revision 1.0 of this board might not support Ryzen 5000 series CPUs at all.


Is there a way to flash the bios without going back to the previous cpu
?

No, you have to install the compatible (old) CPU again, flash the new firmware, then finally install the new CPU and it should work.
Please note it may take more than one step because a certain minimum version is required in order to upgrade to the latest one.
